# Interrupt user navigating by my ad page

Tags: networking, network-programming, ads

I would like implement next sceario: I've got a wi-fi router, which can be use for internet access. Everyone who goes to new internet site through this router with his browser should find himself at my html page with some ads, and button. When button is clicked user is redirected to site, which he wants to visit. When user goes to another site, he should see my ad page again.
Is it possible implement this workflow? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Ugh, that sounds like extremely expensive internet access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is a [Captive Portal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal).

I doubt many routers have that tight of a restriction out-of-the-box, but you could probably do it with [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index).